How to handle changes to a field in environment.ts in Angular?
First, due diligence. Here I see how the change detection works. Here is a blog elaborating and explaining the subject. Here I can read about environments. Here I have examples on the change detection on component's parts.
Nowhere I look, I can see how to react to changes in the fields of the injected environment. So I can't even provide a minimal example.
Is it possible to detect a change in a variable that I import into my component like this?
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

The reason is that I'm toggling the language marker in that file and I want to all my pipes for translation to be recalculated. It work in the component that the click happens in but then, I need to distribute said change to all the other parts.
onLingoClick() {
  // Lang is an enum containing language codes.
  const count = Object.keys(Lang).length / 2;
  environment.language = (environment.language + 1) % count;
  this.lingo = environment.language;
}

Then, I have the pipe doing the projection of the code to one of the translations.
@Pipe({ name: 'lang' })
export class LanguagePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(code: string, lang: Lang = environment.language): string { ... }
}

Is it even doable? If not, how can I approach it in a better way? I could register each component and listen to the language changes using an observable. However, it seems like a bit of an overkill.

You are using the wrong file environment.ts is mean't to be configured once and run during ng build but never being dynamically modified! Use a service variable instead! and the value should be passed to the pipes as a parameter

That doesn't seem like a good way to use the environment file (build time config injection is problematic in general for reasons I explain here). If you want to react to updates across the app then a service exposing an observable (or signal, if you're using that paradigm in newer Angular) is exactly what to do (example here) and it's not clear to me why you consider that "overkill".

@jonrsharpe Maybe overkill wasn't the best choice of a word. I do respect your input, so I'll use that that suggestion. I was trying to find a lazy way around it (and also, I have two junior engineers under me who are a bit reluctant to observables because "that's not how we did it in React").   :D
